# Setting Text Box Value From Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Im trying to set the values of my text boxes from a WebGrid im MVC 3. Im able to get the data using Jquery. the boxes populates for half a second the resets. Any ideas why?

```
$(".select").click(function () {
    var contribution = $(".select");
    var parent = contribution.parent();
    var children = parent.children();
    var Group = children.filter(':nth-child(2)');
    var Level = children.filter(':nth-child(3)');
    var effective = children.filter(':nth-child(6)');
    var amount = children.filter(':nth-child(7)');
    //alert(amount.html());
    document.getElementById("GroupDescription").value = Group.html();
    document.getElementById("LevelDescription").value = Level.html();
    document.getElementById("Date").value = effective.html();
    document.getElementById("Amount").value = amount.html();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent the default action.

```
$(".select").click(function (e) {
    var contribution = $(".select");
    var parent = contribution.parent();
    var children = parent.children();
    var Group = children.filter(':nth-child(2)');
    var Level = children.filter(':nth-child(3)');
    var effective = children.filter(':nth-child(6)');
    var amount = children.filter(':nth-child(7)');
    //alert(amount.html());
    document.getElementById("GroupDescription").value = Group.html();
    document.getElementById("LevelDescription").value = Level.html();
    document.getElementById("Date").value = effective.html();
    document.getElementById("Amount").value = amount.html();
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: You might have gotten it with `e.preventDefault();` nice catch. Upvoted ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any particular reason to use `document.getElementById(id)` use the jQuery equivelant `$('#id')` it is much more powerfull and you're loading jQuery anyway.

Heres a bit of psuedo code that should give you an idea how to set the textbox value:

```
$('#textbox').val(value);
```

To get the current value you just us `.val()` so without the argument. I hope this helps you.

[Here is the documentation on the `.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

if whatever is a `.select` is a button in a form, then its default action (submit) may be happening. Try a return false or preventDefault, like ...

```
$(".select").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#GroupDescription').attr('value', Group.html());
```